# How to auto fill date and auto fill time without inputting date on php mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

How to auto fill this two input without inputting?

```
<input type="time" name="Time" id="Time" value="" />
```

I want to automatically fill date and time without inputting according to the desktop date and time.

Comment: `new Date()` in JS will provide you the end user time, you did not describe the use case so you can assign this input whenever you need.

Answer (score 3):

The code for HTML:

```html
<input type="time" id="time_">
```

```js
var now = new Date();
var current_time  = `${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}`
document.querySelector('#time_').value = current_time;
```

```html
<input type="time" id="time_">
```

Here is the code for getting current time using javascript:

```
var now = new Date();
var current_time  = `${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}`
```

If you want to add this using javascript then:
document.querySelector('#time_').value = current_time;

And if you want this in jquery then:

```
$("#time_").val(current_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by javascript.

```
<input type="date" name="Date" id="Date" value="" />
<input type="time" name="Time" id="Time" value="" />

<script>
  //get current date-time of system like Desktop , Server etc....
  const now = new Date();

  //format date and time as string types
  const dateStr = now.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  const timeStr = now.toTimeString().slice(0, 5);

  //set values inside HTML tags
  document.getElementById('Date').value = dateStr;
  document.getElementById('Time').value = timeStr;
</script>
```

Comment: If it helps you then you can tick as right answer and upvote it for others. Enjoy ☺️

Answer (score 0):

### You can use the PHP date() function.

First make a PHP file with the same name as your html file and copy your code on to the PHP file and then replace your input tag with the code given below (. You can change the time format however as you like

- "Y:m:d" = 2023:01:01
- "h/i/s" = 12/34/45
- "Y/m/d h/i/s" = 2023/01/01 12/34/45

```
<input type="text" name="" id="" value="<?php echo(date("Y:m:d h:i:s", time())); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can fill almost any input with its `value` property.

In javascript:

```
document.querySelector('#Time').value = '07:30'
```

For it to consume your system time create a date object and feed the hours and minutes to the input

```
const now = new Date();
document.querySelector('#Time').value = `${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}`
```

Comment: Second script will fail on all times that do not have 2 digits in both hours and minutes